# does filetype equals pdf in google cse list work in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api-client, google-search-api

I am using `google custom search` through the api `google_api_client python`. I want to retrieve the pdf documents for a particular query. Below is the function that does it.

```
 def query_results(service,q=None,startIndex=1,siteSearch=None,fileType=None):
    return service.cse().list(
        q=q,
        cx='000906600611484344115:o9lfdh9y1m5',
        start=startIndex,
        siteSearch=siteSearch,
        fileType=fileType,
        safe='off'
      ).execute()
```

When i call the above method passing `q="alienware", filetype="pdf" and siteSearch="google.com"`, I get hardly one result. But then when I type the same query `filetype:pdf alienware` in google search through browser, `I got plenty of results.` Did I do any wrong ? or Is there an issue with the api itself ?.

**When i say `I got plenty of results`, I mean the below image**

[image]

Below is the configuration of custom search
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `siteSearch="google.com"` means you will only search pages on google.com.  It is equivalent to searching for `site:google.com` on Google.  Remove the siteSearch and you should get the expected results.